# Как ускорить компиляцию?

Tags: c, c++

Если проект очень велик и собирается реально долго - пять минут и более на 2-х процессорной машине, как можно ускорить компиляцию (на той же машине)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Часто случается, что во время компиляции одни и те же заголовочники подключают в одном и том же окружении (с одинаковыми макросами). В таком случае, полезно, чтобы компилятор не анализировал заголовочники на каждый .c-файл. Для этого предназначены [Precompiled headers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) и [ещё](http://chabster.blogspot.com/2008/06/precompiled-headers-explained.html).

Если под рукой несколько машин, то можно попрбовать распределённую компиляцию. Например, с помощью [distcc](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distcc).

Кроме того, можно попробовать посмотреть на сам ваш код. Возможно, следует упростить какие-то конструкции, связанные с шаблонами. Это может быть актуально, если вы активно используете метапрограммирование.

Вам также может помочь хорошая модульность приложения, тогда можно будет пересобирать что-то только при необходимости.

Ну и само собой разумеется, что надо использовать make с проверкой таймстемпов и с параллельной сборкой (Например, make -j4).

И напоследок, стоит почитать общие рассуждения на эту тему. На том же [SO поднималась эта тема.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373142/what-techniques-can-be-used-to-speed-up-c-compilation-times)